# Windows Phone Back Button with Angular routes

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, internet-explorer-10

We have an angular app which works fine is most of the devices and browsers (yay!). But Windows phone 8 with IE gives us headaches with the devices back button. We have used angular-route.je to route withing the app and it has usual # based routes. If we navigate to to or more routes in succession and press devices back button {or a button with history.back() } it take you to the default route (index.html).

Ex. 
navigate to ,
index.html -> index.html#/page1 ->  index.html#/page2 ->  index.html#/page3
Now the device back button with take the user to index.html instead of index.html#/page2

Web doesn't give much help so far for us and we are wondering whether we have done something wrong.

Comment: I'm curious—does it work on IE on desktop? Anyway, don't quote me on this, but I seem to remember IE having a very slightly buggy implementation of the history API with respect to hash fragments. Would it be possible to use Angular's HTML5 mode? That would likely be more consistent (though obviously *less* supported by browsers that don't support the history API at all).

Comment: @AlexisKing it works fine on IE and Edge on desktops. Unfortunately HTML5 mode is not an option for us at this moment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the end we figured out that it was an issue with the Angular version we were using (V 1.2.4). Upgraded to a later one (1.4.7) solved the issue.

Note: I think even version 1.3.0 have the fix in it